# HTML5 Sortable: change into drag and drop only right

Tags: html, jquery-ui-sortable

The code of HTML5 sortable (http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/) with Connected Sortable Lists is based on drag and dropping an item of the right list to a *li* at the left list; either above or below it.

Is there a way how to define 5 slots at the left where the users can drag and drop them too, so only the 5 elements at the right are drag and dropable?

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8WUt/13/)

You can drag items from the left to the slots of the right.
You can change an item from slot and if you dbl-click on it, it returns where it comes from, on the left.

This is not perfect, it probably needs upgrade to fit your needs, but you got the way to do it...

HTML :

```
<ul class="right">
    <li draggable="true" class="slot">Slot1</li>
    <li draggable="true" class="slot">Slot2</li>
    <li draggable="true" class="slot">Slot3</li>
    <li draggable="true" class="slot">Slot4</li>
    <li draggable="true" class="slot">Slot5</li>
</ul>

<ul class="left">
    <li draggable="true" class="item">Item1</li>
    <li draggable="true" class="item">Item2</li>
    <li draggable="true" class="item">Item3</li>
    <li draggable="true" class="item">Item4</li>
    <li draggable="true" class="item">Item5</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('.item')
    .each(function(i){ $(this).data('i', i);})
    .on({dragstart:function(e){
            console.log('ITEM : dragstart');
            draggedItem = $(this);
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
         },
         dragend:function(e){e.preventDefault();},
         dragenter:function(e){e.preventDefault();},
         dragover:function(e){e.preventDefault();},
         dragleave:function(e){e.preventDefault();},
         drop: function(e){e.preventDefault();},
         dblclick:function(e){
             if (1 === $(this).parent('.slot.filled').length) {
                 console.log('ITEM : dblclick');
                 var i = $(this).data('i');
                 var last_before = $('.left > .item')
                                   .filter(function(){
                                       return $(this).data('i') < i; 
                                   })
                                   .last();
                 $(this).parent('.slot').removeClass('filled');
                 if (0 === last_before.length){
                     $('.left').prepend($(this));   
                 } else {
                     last_before.after($(this));   
                 }
             }
             e.preventDefault();
         }
    });
$('.slot') 
    .on({dragstart:function(e){e.preventDefault();},    
         dragend:function(e){e.preventDefault();},    
         dragenter:function(e){e.preventDefault();},    
         dragover:function(e){e.preventDefault()},    
         dragleave:function(e){e.preventDefault();},    
         drop:function(e){
             console.log('SLOT : drop');
             draggedItem.parent('.slot').removeClass('filled');
             $(this).filter(':not(.filled)')
             .append(draggedItem)
             .addClass('filled');

             console.log('item:',draggedItem.data('i'),
                         'slot:', $(this).index('.slot'));

             // write you extras code here

             e.preventDefault();
         }    
    })
;
```

FYI : I chose to overwrite all the drag'n drop functions (for items and slots), because I wanted to beat any tricky behavior. I am not sure it is mandatory, but I did not have time to test every combination.